# Scrolling Widgets like one Dashboard - FLUTTER

Tags: json, dart, flutter, dashboard

I'm trying to build a screen with some reports in there, just like a `Dashboard`, i move my fingers to down and appears some information, like when you scroll down `Facebook`.

```
new CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                      [
                        new RelatorioVendPeriodoAPeriodo(),
                        new RelatorioMensals(),
                        new RelatorioDiasDaSemanas(),
                        new RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo(),
                        new RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos(),
//                        new RelatorioContaAssinadaCliente(),
                      ]
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
```

And it is working well, `BUT` when i scroll down the report that i already saw disappear. When my report dissapear i need to `RELOAD` it again, and this reports i get with a Json Request.

**I want to make a Dashboard, on this example, load 5 request and when i go up the report still loaded there.**

Comment: Storing a widget that is not on screen may cause extra ram usage. why don't you store the JSON response in the parent widget(e.g. CustomScrollView) and use it in child widget?

Comment: @Yamin, good day, how i can do it? i tried it: cacheExtent: 100000.0, and worked well, but do you have another ideia?

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this goal.update your question and put the complete code of the current widget and the service that calls the backend. I will put my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
new CustomScrollView(
          cacheExtent: height * 5,
            slivers: [
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      new RelatorioVendPeriodoAPeriodo(),
//                      new RelatorioMensals(),
                      new RelatorioDiasDaSemanas(),
                      new RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo(),
                      new RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos(),
//                        new RelatorioContaAssinadaCliente(),
                    ]
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
```

**cacheExtent: height * 5,** -> the code that salved me.